# Replacing a character with \n in a regex then turning the text into a quanteda corpus

Tags: r, regex, gsub, quanteda

I have some text I have OCR'd. The OCR put a lot of newlines (\n) were they were not supposed to be. But also missed a lot of new lines that were supposed to be there.

I want to remove the existing newlines and replace them with spaces. Then replace specific characters with newlines in the raw text. Then turn the documents into a corpus in quanteda.

I can create a basic corpus. But the trouble is I can't then break it up into paragraphs. If I use
corpus_reshape(corps, to ="paragraphs", use_docvars = TRUE)
It will not break up the document.

If I use corpus_segment(corps, pattern = "\n")

I get an error.

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library(quanteda)
library(readtext)

# Here is a sample Text
sample <- "Hello my name is Christ-
ina. 50 Sometimes we get some we-


irdness

Hello my name is Michael, 
sometimes we get some weird,


 and odd, results-- 50 I want to replace the 
 50s
"



# Removing the existing breaks
sample <- gsub("\n", " ", sample)
sample <- gsub(" {2,}", " ", sample)
# Adding new breaks
sample <- gsub("50", "\n", sample)

# I can create a corpus
corps <- corpus(sample, compress = FALSE)
summary(corps, 1)

# But I can't change to paragraphs
corp_para <- corpus_reshape(corps, to ="paragraphs", use_docvars = TRUE)
summary(corp_para, 1)

# But I can't change to paragraphs
corp_para <- corpus_reshape(corps, to ="paragraphs", use_docvars = TRUE)
summary(corp_para, 1)

corp_segmented <-  corpus_segment(corps, pattern = "\n")

# The \n characters are in both documents.... 
corp_para$documents$texts
sample
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using regular expression replacement to clean your text before making it into a corpus.  The trick in your text is figure out where you want to remove newlines, and where you want to keep them.  I'm guessing from your question that you want to remove the occurrences of "50", but also probably join the words split by hyphens and a newline.  You probably also want to keep two newlines between texts?

Many users prefer the simpler interface of the **stringr** package, but I've always tended to use **stringi** (on which **stringr** is built) instead.  It allows for vectorized replacement, so you can feed it a vector of patterns to match, and the replacements, in one function call.

```r
library("stringi")

sample2 <- stri_replace_all_regex(sample, c("\\-\\n+", "\\n+", "50"), c("", "\n", "\n"),
  vectorize_all = FALSE
)
cat(sample2)
## Hello my name is Christina. 
##  Sometimes we get some weirdness
## Hello my name is Michael, 
## sometimes we get some weird,
##  and odd, results-- 
##  I want to replace the 
##  
## s
```

Here, you match `"\\n"` as a regular expression *pattern* but use just `"\n"` as the (literal) *replacement*.

There are two newlines before the last "s" in the replaced text because a) there was already one after the "s" in "50s" and b) we added one by replacing 50 with a new `"\n"`.

Now you can construct a corpus with `quanteda::corpus(sample2)`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I still cannot use corpus_reshape() to get paragraphs.  The new paragraphs created by stri_replace_all_regex() do not seem to create partitions.

Comment: `corpus_reshape(x, to = "paragraphs")` looks for two newlines as the paragraph delimiters. You would need to add a second newline in your text before a marker for your paragraph, such as before "Hello". This was not a clear part of your question however.

Comment: That did it, thanks. You're right my question was not clear. I am learning - sorry about that.